# Why won't prove accept -MCarp=verbose?

Tags: perl, testing, carp

I ran this test script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 3;
use Carp;

ok(1<2);
pass();
fail();
croak "example";
```

using the command line `prove -MCarp=verbose -v foo.pl`, and got the following errors:

```
Subroutine App::Prove::verbose redefined at /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/App/Prove.pm line 407
        App::Prove::_load_extension('App::Prove=HASH(0x683718)', 'Carp=verbose') called at /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/App/Prove.pm line 419
        App::Prove::_load_extensions('App::Prove=HASH(0x683718)', 'ARRAY(0x683850)') called at /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/App/Prove.pm line 481
        App::Prove::run('App::Prove=HASH(0x683718)') called at /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/bin/prove line 11
Undefined subroutine &Carp::verbose called at /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/App/Prove.pm line 484.
```

If I run it using `perl -MCarp=verbose foo.pl` there's no problem. What is causing `prove` to reject verbose Carp? How can I get a full callstack from my tests when they `croak` without global replacing `croak` to `confess`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`prove -M` does not appear to be equivalent to `perl -M`.  It appears to load a prove extension, not load a module into your tests.  The docs are totally unclear on this point, but the code in App::Prove is not.  So `prove -MCarp=verbose` imports Carp::verbose into App::Prove causing the problem above.

A simple way to do what you want is to use the PERL5OPT environment variable plus [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp::Always) which will turn all warns and dies (and carps and croaks) into stack traces.

```
PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always prove ...
```

This has the added benefit of working in any situation, with or without prove.

Comment: okay, you're right, this is *also* true. Missed the part where prove's `-M` overrides the harness class. Nonetheless, the bug I pointed out seems to exist. :)

Comment: hmm, investigation shows you are right. `prove -MMoose foo.pl` doesn't load Moose (according to `%INC`), while the `PERL5OPT` trick does.

Answer (score 3):

prove has a very different set of command line arguments than perl, being a completely different program?

prove's -M is, I believe, intended for enabling pragmas; Carp actually exports a forward reference to a verbose() subroutine, which interferes with prove's inner workings.

You can create a small module like this:

```
# Verbme.pm
use Carp;
$Carp::Verbose = 1;
```

and enable it from prove:

```
prove -MVerbme -v foo.pl
```

though.

Comment: The code in App::Prove hands the stuff in -M to App::Prove->_load_extension() which is used to load prove plug ins.  Any importing is explicitly done inside App::Prove and it even looks for a special load() method.  Its a badly documented feature.

Comment: @Schwern: but -P is for loading plugins.  And I can't believe it an accident that -M applies to not just prove, but also the tests run.  Though I guess stranger accidents have happened.

Comment: having done some tests printing out `%INC`, it seems that prove -M does *not* load modules into the tests run.

Comment: Yes, -P is for loading prove "plugins". -M is for loading prove "modules". `prove -M` does not apply the module to the tests, only to prove.  The only difference between a prove "module" and a prove "plugin" appears to be that prove will prepend "App::Prove::Plugin::" to a plugin name for you.  The code in App::Prove->run is pretty clear on the matter.  I agree its designed for maximum confusion.

Comment: @Schwern: thanks, for some reason I had myself convinced -M was propagating into the run tests, but I was clearly mistaken somehow

Answer (score 2):

Carp uses Exporter's `EXPORT_FAIL` mechanism to handle the `verbose` "option" to `import`, which is pretty much wrong, as `Exporter::Heavy` will still try to assign `*Carp::verbose` to `*{"$callerpkg::verbose"}` despite the fact that it was "failed". Unfortunately, `App::Prove` has a verbose sub that it depends on to work, and your -M option causes the import to happen within `App::Prove`. I'm not sure who is to blame here -- `Carp` for (ab)using `EXPORT_FAIL` in this way, or `Exporter::Heavy` for not removing stuff from `@imports` if it's in the `@failed` list, but together they're breaking it :)

Comment: Well, OP's problem as posted is that Prove is blowing up because its `verbose` method was trashed. Although I suppose if that didn't happen, it would have blown up differently shortly after.

Comment: if it didn't blow up, it would have silently not worked. You can see this with, say, `prove -MMoose` which will simply not load Moose and run the test regardless. So I was lucky that it blew up spectacularly rather than failing silently :)